# Multiple dataframe joins

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I received multiple csv files that contain customer historical information:

- CustomerInfo.csv: ssn, name
- CustomerAddresses.csv: ssn, addr_type, street, state, zipcode
- CustomerPhoneNumbers.csv: ssn, phone_type, phone_num
- CustomerCreditHistory.csv: ssn, from_date, to_date, score

I read these files as Dataframe and need to join them to construct the following object model:

```
case class Address(addressType: String, street: String, state: String, zipCode: String)
case class Phone(phoneType: String, number: String)
case class CreditHistory(fromDate: Date, toDate: Date, score: Double)
case class Customer(ssn: String, name: String, addresses: Seq[Address], phones: Seq[Phone], credits: Seq[CreditHistory])
```

If you look at this, each customer can have more than 1 addresses, phones, or credit history.

What will be the best way to join these 4 dataframes in order to be able to construct the Customer object?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is too general to answer. Please, provide the headers of each type of CSV file, the number of CSV files and the types of Scala objects you'd like to produce at the end.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Also, when you say that you are looking for "the best way", can you share the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Spark 1.6.1 is what we are using. I don't actually have much code written for this yet. One idea is just to join all 4 dataframes and ended up with a cartesian product. Other is to perform a group by ssn first for Address, Credit History and Phone before joining with Customer Info, but this is causing lots of stages.